# Converting Color Fingerprint Image to Black & White

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fingerprint, image-segmentation

I need to convert a sample fingerprint image into black and white, where the finger color acts as a foreground color and the background color is black. It's needed in MATLAB code format.... For example, I need to convert image from: [image]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/15/Fingerprint_detail_on_male_finger.jpg/800px-Fingerprint_detail_on_male_finger.jpg))</sub>

to a black-and-white image.

EDIT: I used multiple masks, like prewitt: http://i43.tinypic.com/1z7w60.jpg
Canny Detector: http://i44.tinypic.com/2ujtt6u.jpg

I'm not getting lines on blurry here.

Comment: Ugh, the images _could_ be minimized...

Comment: you cannot expect to recover the fingerprint at the blurry parts of the finger. Please post a new input image that is more representative of your task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Shai said, you can only expect good results in regions of the image that are in focus.
Try starting with these algorithms:

**[Link 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method)**

**[Link 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector)**

Comment: Yeah, that's one issue with the project.... Getting all the lines to be focussed. Maybe a capacitive sensor or simple plastic. Canny Edge detector looks feasible. I'll try it ASAP.